# Ajax request in ajax request doesnt send back SQL information

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I'm trying to update my upvotes once someone upvoted or downvoted something. So in the done() method from my ajax i make another ajax request in order of updating my upvote count on the webpage.

```
 $.post( "../ajax/add_interet.php", {'idregle' : idregle ,'vote' : 1})
                .done(function(data){
                   // getJSON = another ajax request to update my upvotes
                   $.getJSON('../ajax/update_interet.php',{ 'idregle' : idregle }, function(data){

                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                   });

                })
                .fail(function(data){
                    $('.error').html(data);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                })
        });
```

I recieve in return :{up:null, down:null}.
I tried my SQL and it worked great but here is it in any case :

```
$R_Id = intval($_POST['idregle']);

$getcount = $db->prepare('SELECT SUM(I_Up) AS up, SUM(I_Down) AS down FROM I_Interet WHERE I_IdRegle = :idregle');
$getcount->execute(array(
        'idregle' => $R_Id
        ));
$tags = $getcount->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($tags);
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` sends a HTTP GET request with `idregle` added as URL paramter.

But on the server you read the parameter from `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`, therefore most likely the query does not match any records and the sum functions return `NULL`.

Comment: aaaaaaaah $.getJSON uses $_GET ! I didn't gave attention to that. Thanks a lot !